# SQL: case_when syntax error, compare the value and show related name

Tags: sql

My table data:

```
bookname1 price1 bookname2 price2 bookname3 price3
--------------------------------------------------
abc        1     n          2      zx          3
abc        1     n          2      zx          3
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    *, 
    CASE WHEN (price1 >= price2)
       THEN price1
       ELSE 
          CASE WHEN (price2 >= price3) 
                  THEN price2
                  ELSE price3 
          END
    END 
FROM
    book
```

But running this query returns nothing. I hope to compare 3 price columns (find the maximum) and return their bookname and price.

Desired results:

```
bookname price1
----------------
zx       3
zx       3
```

Thanks for teaching.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I edit right now, is it clearer than before?

Comment: . . And tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You should also read up on database normalization - you have repeating values and the problem you have is a direct result of your bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would appear to want:

```
select b.*, 
       (case when price1 >= price2 and price1 >= price3 then price1
             when price2 >= price3 then price2
             else price3
        end) as max_price,
       (case when price1 >= price2 and price1 >= price3 then bookname1
             when price2 >= price3 then bookname2
             else bookname3
        end) as max_price
from book b;
```

Comment: Thank your patience as I edit the question several times. == I do not use the database. I'd not use the database. I search what wrong for me.I miss something before using SQL.Sorry for causing inconvenience. Thank your patience as I edit the question several times. I know it (sql and the logic)right now.Thanks

Comment: @hahakwok: note that in many DBMS you can simplify the expression to evaluate the max_price with the expression `greatest(price1, price2, price3)` - but not all DBMS support that.

Answer (score 0):

The first "else" is not correct.

```
    select *,  
    case 
    when price1 >= price2 then price1 
    when price2 >= price3 then price2 
    else  price3 end 
    from book
```

Comment: it shows Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "case": syntax error

Comment: @hahakwok You need to start your comment with @ JBrooks or I don't get notified that you posted one to me.